# Tough Polynomial Root Problem

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Let $S$ be the set of all polynomials of the form $z^3 + az^2 + bz + c$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers. Find the number of polynomials in $S$ such that each of its roots $z$ satisfies either $|z| = 20$ or $|z| = 13$.

By $z$ I usually assume the root is a complex number. If $|z| = 20$, there are 4 choices,

$$z_1 = 20, z_2 = -20, z_3 = c + di, z_4 = c - di$$ and same for $|z| = 13$. Also, $z_1 = x+ iy$ and $z_2$ is the conjugate is also a possibility.

Since $|c + di| = 20, c^2 + d^2 = x^2 + y^2 = 400$.

Vieta's formulas gives:

$$\sum \text{roots} = -a = \{2c, 2x + 2c \}$$

Here is the issue, $a$ has infinite values if $c \in \mathbb{R}$, but only finite if $c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I don't get your comment about the four choices... $z=20e^{i\theta}$, with $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$... You don't have four possible choices for $|z|=20$, but an infinity...

Comment: mmm, that makes life harder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1**

> Prove that every polynomial with real coefficients has its complex roots in conjugate pairs.

**Hint 2**

> Prove that the above implies that the original cubic factorizes into a linear and a quadratic factor.

**Hint 3**

> Use your reasoning to determine what roots are possible since the above factors must have integer coefficients.

Comment: Where is this quartic you are talking about?

Comment: @mrf: Oops I thought the question involved a quartic!

Answer (score 0):

Viete's formulas are all interesting to use:

$z_1+z_2+z_3=-a$

$z_1z_2+z_1z_3+z_2z_3=b$

$z_1z_2z_3=-c$

And then you have indeed four choices: either all your roots have modulus $20$, or only two (and the other $13$), or one, or none...

Then use the fact that if $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is a solution, then $\bar z$ is a solution too.

It should then go on very quickly.